# Google EntitiesUsageReport API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

Has anyone used the EntitiesUsageReport API?  I am looking to use the gplus_communities entity type via the Advanced Google Services in Google Apps Script.

See example:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-reports

I have used the AdminReports.UserUsageReport.get and AdminReports.UserUsageReport.get, am I able to use EntitiesUsageReport in the same sort of way?  Has anyone got an examples of how to use this to get G+ community data?

Thanks

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Comment: I managed to get this working, I was having trouble with the optional arguments. AdminReports.EntityUsageReports.get(entityType, entityKey, date, optionalArgs) works fine now :)